# AWS Cognito Authorization code grant flow without using the hosted UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Using AWS's Cognito without the hosted UI, given a username, and password I would like to receive an Authorization code grant without using the hosted ui.

Is this possible? I am writing my own sign up, log in forms but cannot seem to find documentation on this subject.

Currently I can use AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider and the initiateAuth function to exchange username password for tokens, but I do not want to return those tokens in the redirect URL, I would rather return an authorization code grant that can be exchanged for tokens.

So how can I using initiateAuth receive authorization code grant instead of tokens.

UPDATE: Using the correct answer below,  this is how I ended up doing it in node.

```
const base64url = require('base64url');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const request = require('request');
const querystring = require ('querystring');

function generateCodeVerifierHash(code_verifier) {
  return crypto.createHmac('SHA256', code_verifier)
  .digest('base64');
}

function generateCodeVerifier() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789._`-";

  for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return base64url.encode(text);
}

var CLIENT_ID="Your Client Id";
var CLIENT_SECRET="Your Client Secret";
var RESPONSE_TYPE="code";
var REDIRECT_URI= encodeURIComponent("Your Redirect Url");
var SCOPE="openid";
var AUTH_DOMAIN= "Your Cognito Auth Domain";
var USERNAME="User's Username";
var PASSWORD="User's Password";
var CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD="S256";

// Challenge
var code_verifier = generateCodeVerifier();
var code_challenge = generateCodeVerifierHash(code_verifier);

// Get CSRF token from /oauth2/authorize endpoint
var csrfRequestUrl = `https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=${RESPONSE_TYPE}&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&scope=${SCOPE}&code_challenge_method=${CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD}&code_challenge=${code_challenge}`;
// Post CSRF Token and username/password to /login endpoint
var codeRequestUrl = `https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/login?response_type=${RESPONSE_TYPE}&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}`;

request.get(csrfRequestUrl, (err, res, body) => {
    var XSRFTOKEN = res.headers['set-cookie'].filter( (header) => header.substring(0,10) == 'XSRF-TOKEN')[0];

    form = {
      '_csrf': `${XSRFTOKEN.split(';')[0].split('=')[1]}`,
      'username': `${USERNAME}`,
      'password': `${PASSWORD}`,
    }

    var formData = querystring.stringify(form);
    var contentLength = formData.length;

    request({
      headers: {
        'Content-Length': contentLength,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Cookie': `${XSRFTOKEN}`,
      },
      uri: codeRequestUrl,
      body: formData,
      method: 'POST'
    }, function (err, res, body) {
      var authorizationCodeGrant = res.headers.location.split('=')[1];
      console.log(authorizationCodeGrant);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have been struggling with this exact same problem for a while and finally stumbled upon your question and answer. Thank you so much for posting your code, it really helped me understand.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no way to do that by using initiateAuth and respondToAuthChallenge since that involves just authentication against your user pool and the end result will be that you will get tokens.

However, it is totally possible to interact with the authorize, token, and login endpoints through code. If you have a look at the following shell script code, you will have an idea of the information that needs to be passed to the endpoints:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#===============================================================================
# SET AUTH DOMAIN
#===============================================================================
AUTH_DOMAIN="MY-DOMAIN.auth.REGION.amazoncognito.com"

#===============================================================================
# AUTH CODE/IMPLICIT GRANTS, WITHOUT PKCE, WITHOUT CLIENT SECRET
#===============================================================================

## Set constants ##
CLIENT_ID="USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID"
RESPONSE_TYPE="code"
#RESPONSE_TYPE="token"
REDIRECT_URI="https://example.com/"
SCOPE="openid"

USERNAME="testuser"
PASSWORD="testpassword"

## Get CSRF token and LOGIN URL from /oauth2/authorize endpoint ##
curl_response="$(
    curl -qv "https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=${RESPONSE_TYPE}&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&scope=${SCOPE}" 2>&1
)"
curl_redirect="$(printf "%s" "$curl_response" \
                    | awk '/^< Location: / {
                        gsub(/\r/, ""); # Remove carriage returns
                        print $3;       # Print redirect URL
                    }')"
csrf_token="$(printf "%s" "$curl_response" \
                   | awk '/^< Set-Cookie:/ {
                       gsub(/^XSRF-TOKEN=|;$/, "", $3); # Remove cookie name and semi-colon
                       print $3;                        # Print cookie value
                    }')"

## Get auth code or tokens from /login endpoint ##
curl_response="$(
    curl -qv "$curl_redirect" \
        -H "Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=${csrf_token}; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly" \
        -d "_csrf=${csrf_token}" \
        -d "username=${USERNAME}" \
        -d "password=${PASSWORD}" 2>&1
)"
curl_redirect="$(printf "%s" "$curl_response" \
                    | awk '/^< Location: / {
                        gsub(/\r/, ""); # Remove carriage returns
                        print $3;       # Print redirect URL
                    }')"
auth_code="$(printf "%s" "$curl_redirect" \
                | awk '{
                    sub(/.*code=/, ""); # Remove everything before auth code
                    print;              # Print auth code
                }')"

## Get tokens from /oauth2/token endpoint ##
GRANT_TYPE="authorization_code"
curl "https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/oauth2/token" \
    -d "grant_type=${GRANT_TYPE}" \
    -d "client_id=${CLIENT_ID}" \
    -d "code=${auth_code}" \
    -d "redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}"

#===============================================================================
# AUTH CODE/IMPLICIT GRANTS, WITH PKCE, WITH CLIENT SECRET
#===============================================================================

## Set constants ##
CLIENT_ID="USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID"
CLIENT_SECRET="USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET"
RESPONSE_TYPE="code"
#RESPONSE_TYPE="token"
REDIRECT_URI="https://example.com/"
SCOPE="openid"

USERNAME="testuser"
PASSWORD="testpassword"

## Create a code_verifier and code_challenge ##
CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD="S256"
# code_verifier = random, 64-char string consisting of chars between letters,
#                 numbers, periods, underscores, tildes, or hyphens; the string
#                 is then base64-url encoded
code_verifier="$(cat /dev/urandom \
                    | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9._~-' \
                    | fold -w 64 \
                    | head -n 1 \
                    | base64 \
                    | tr '+/' '-_' \
                    | tr -d '='
                )"
# code_challenge = SHA-256 hash of the code_verifier; it is then base64-url
#                  encoded
code_challenge="$(printf "$code_verifier" \
                    | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary \
                    | base64 \
                    | tr '+/' '-_' \
                    | tr -d '='
                )"

## Get CSRF token from /oauth2/authorize endpoint ##
curl_response="$(
    curl -qv "https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=${RESPONSE_TYPE}&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&scope=${SCOPE}&code_challenge_method=${CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD}&code_challenge=${code_challenge}" 2>&1
)"
curl_redirect="$(printf "%s" "$curl_response" \
                    | awk '/^< Location: / {
                        gsub(/\r/, ""); # Remove carriage returns
                        print $3;       # Print redirect URL
                    }')"
csrf_token="$(printf "%s" "$curl_response" \
                | awk '/^< Set-Cookie:/ {
                    gsub(/^XSRF-TOKEN=|;$/, "", $3); # Remove cookie name and semi-colon
                    print $3;                        # Print cookie value
                }')"

## Get auth code or tokens from /login endpoint ##
curl_response="$(
    curl -qv "$curl_redirect" \
        -H "Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=${csrf_token}; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly" \
        -d "_csrf=${csrf_token}" \
        -d "username=${USERNAME}" \
        -d "password=${PASSWORD}" 2>&1
)"
curl_redirect="$(printf "%s" "$curl_response" \
                    | awk '/^< Location: / {
                        gsub(/\r/, ""); # Remove carriage returns
                        print $3;       # Print redirect URL
                    }'
                )"
auth_code="$(printf "%s" "$curl_redirect" \
                | awk '{
                    sub(/.*code=/, ""); # Remove everything before auth code
                    print;              # Print auth code
                }')"

## Get tokens from /oauth2/token endpoint ##
authorization="$(printf "${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}" \
                    | base64 \
                    | tr -d "\n" # Remove line feed
                )"
GRANT_TYPE="authorization_code"
curl "https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/oauth2/token" \
    -H "Authorization: Basic ${authorization}" \
    -d "grant_type=${GRANT_TYPE}" \
    -d "client_id=${CLIENT_ID}" \
    -d "code=${auth_code}" \
    -d "redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}" \
    -d "code_verifier=${code_verifier}"

#===============================================================================
# CLIENT CREDENTIALS GRANT
#===============================================================================

## Set constants ##
CLIENT_ID="USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID"
CLIENT_SECRET="USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET"
GRANT_TYPE="client_credentials"

## Get access token from /oauth2/token endpoint ##
authorization="$(printf "${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}" \
                    | base64 \
                    | tr -d "\n" # Remove line feed
                )"
curl "https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/oauth2/token" \
    -H "Authorization: Basic ${authorization}" \
    -d "grant_type=${GRANT_TYPE}"

#===============================================================================
# LOGOUT
#===============================================================================

## Set constants ##
CLIENT_ID="USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID"
REDIRECT_URI="https://example.com/"

## Hit /logout endpoint ##
curl -v "https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/logout?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&logout_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}"
```

Comment: Cognito recently added support for Custom Domains so you don't need to do this anymore: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain.html#cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain-console-step-1

Comment: Works pretty well! It seems that the response from `oauth2/authorize` now returns two Set-Cookie headers, so I had to make one adaptation to the script. `| awk '/^< Set-Cookie:/ {` -> `| awk '/^< Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=/ {`

Comment: @IonutTrestian, there is still no way to gain the authorization code via hosting your own UI.

Comment: @miyasudokoro stuck on the same issue, if we hosting our own UI is there a way to gain the authorization code? Can't find any documentation on amplify for this and the `signIn` API keeps returning all the tokens instead of a code

Comment: @YashKalwani Cognito will redirect the user to the URL you provide as redirect URL with the code set as a URL parameter

Answer (score 1):

While researching this topic I noticed that the documentation for the different Cognito Oauth2 endpoints are lost on many, so I'll paste them here and hope they'll give some clarity

[Authorization endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html): The first step in an Authorization Code flow. This will redirect the user to the provided redirect URL along with the authorization code

[Token endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html): The second step in an Authorization Code flow. This is where you'll trade your Authorization Code for the actual token.