# AWS Cognito Authorization code grant flow without using the hosted UI in 2020

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

My team made a custom Cognito login page using normal AWS SDK JS code that logs users in for a given domain name, functioning via cookies. Now we are asked to support multiple domains, which can't be done via the cookie system, so I am looking into OAuth2. The huge problem with OAuth2 is that I can't find any documentation on how to do OAuth2 using one's custom login page.

The previous best answer on this subject is at [AWS Cognito Authorization code grant flow without using the hosted UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012091/aws-cognito-authorization-code-grant-flow-without-using-the-hosted-ui), but that is now about 2 years old, and I can see that the POST occurring on the hosted login page now includes another base64 piece of information not provided by the old answer, so I am skeptical that answer will still work. Is there still no way to generate the authorization code grant without using the hosted UI?

Comment: Hi! Did you come up with a solution with regards to this issue? It seems that we're facing the same very issue in 2021. It's unbelievable.