# How to use Cognito as OAuth Flow without using Hosted UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I saw some similar questions here before but I couldn`t understand none of them. How can I get an code from OAuth 2 authentication flow without using hosted UI in Cognito ?

I saw that hosted calls a javascript function but I don`t understand how this works and return the code.

Is there any way to call an API directly passing user credentials and has this code generated ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012091/aws-cognito-authorization-code-grant-flow-without-using-the-hosted-ui

Comment: HOLY! It really still works... I saw other questions saying that this answer was outdated due be two years ago. But in fact this answer still works. Thank u so much for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is pretty bad for this - but I got it to work using a customProvider as a property

Auth.federatedSignIn(
{customProvider: "YOUR_CUSTOM_PROVIDER"})

According to:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/a047ce73/packages/auth/src/types/Auth.ts#L74

The whole function based on the AWS tutorial would then be:

```js
      Auth.federatedSignIn(
        {customProvider: "YOUR_CUSTOM_PROVIDER"}
    ).then(cred => {
        // If success, you will get the AWS credentials
        console.log(cred);
        this.setState({
          isAuthorized:true
        })
        this.login()
    }).then(user => {
        // If success, the user object you passed in Auth.federatedSignIn
        console.log(user);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
    });
    }
```