# Prefill Cognito Forms with Logged in user details

Tags: cognitoforms

Please could someone assist or just some advice would be great. I'm looking to prefill a cognito form with the currently logged in users details like Name and Last Name and not just static information. Is this possible to do through cognito forms? I am doing the form through the url method.

I have had no luck in finding a solution so far.

Thanks

Comment: maybe this one will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012091/aws-cognito-authorization-code-grant-flow-without-using-the-hosted-ui