# Forgot password - Cognito Hosted UI and OIDC Endpoint Reference

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, reset-password

I am trying to do my customised UI for Cognito Login and Forgot Password using this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49012091). I am able to do Login request and redirect. Also I am able to get the Reset Password code to the email. But   Confirm password submit request is not working. Also I am not getting any proper error messages from the API End point. I will provide here Login API request and Confirm Password Request.

Login Submit Request:

```
exports.postLogin = async (req, res, next) => {
    const CLIENT_ID = req.query.client_id;
    const RESPONSE_TYPE = 'token';
    const REDIRECT_URI = encodeURIComponent(req.query.redirect_uri);
    const SCOPE = req.query.scope;
    const AUTH_DOMAIN = "<domain>.<region>.amazoncognito.com";
    const USERNAME = req.body.username;
    const PASSWORD = req.body.password
    const state = req.query.state;
    const XSRFTOKEN = req.body._csrf

    let form = {
        '_csrf': XSRFTOKEN,
        'username': `${USERNAME.toLowerCase()}`,
        'password': `${PASSWORD}`,
    }

    const formData = querystring.stringify(form);
    const contentLength = formData.length;

    console.log(formData)

    // Post CSRF Token and username/password to /login endpoint
    const codeRequestUrl = `https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/login?response_type=${RESPONSE_TYPE}&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&state=${state}`;
    console.log(codeRequestUrl)
    request({
        headers: {
            'Content-Length': contentLength,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Cookie': `XSRF-TOKEN=${XSRFTOKEN}; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax`,
        },
        uri: codeRequestUrl,
        body: formData,
        method: 'POST'
    }, (err, response, body) => {
        console.log(body)
        console.log(err);
        console.log(response.headers.location);
        console.log(response.statusCode)
        res.redirect(response.headers.location);
    });
};
```

The above API is working fine. But if the user credential is wrong, the API doesn't providing proper error message.

Confirm Password Submit Request:

```
exports.postConfirmForgotPassword = async (req, res, next) => {
    const req_parsed = new Url(req.url);

    const CLIENT_ID = req.query.client_id;
    const RESPONSE_TYPE = 'token';
    const REDIRECT_URI = encodeURIComponent(req.query.redirect_uri);
    const AUTH_DOMAIN = "<domain>.<region>.amazoncognito.com";
    const USERNAME = req.body.username;
    const ConfirmationCode = req.body.code;
    const Password = req.body.password;
    const state = req.query.state;
    const XSRFTOKEN = req.body._csrf

    let form = {
        '_csrf': XSRFTOKEN,
        'confirmation-code': `${ConfirmationCode}`, // I tried it with sending as 'code', 'confirmationcode'. But nothing is working.
        'password': `${Password}`,
        'username': `${USERNAME}`
    }

    const formData = querystring.stringify(form);
    const contentLength = formData.length;

    console.log(formData)

    // Post CSRF Token and username/password to /login endpoint
    const codeRequestUrl = `https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/confirmForgotPassword?response_type=${RESPONSE_TYPE}&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&state=${state}`;
    console.log(codeRequestUrl)
    request({
        headers: {
            'Content-Length': contentLength,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Cookie': `XSRF-TOKEN=${XSRFTOKEN}; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax`,
        },
        uri: codeRequestUrl,
        body: formData,
        method: 'POST'
    }, (err, response, body) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(response.headers.location);
        console.log(response.statusCode)
        console.log(`/login${req_parsed.query}`)
        res.redirect(`/login${req_parsed.query}`);
    });
};
```

I tried it to send the request body as below too. But nothing is working. Also not seeing any documentation for this in Cognito Side.

```
let form = {
    '_csrf': XSRFTOKEN,
    'code': `${ConfirmationCode}`, 
    'password': `${Password}`,
    'username': `${USERNAME}`
}
```

(or)

```
let form = {
    '_csrf': XSRFTOKEN,
    'confirmationcode': `${ConfirmationCode}`, 
    'password': `${Password}`,
    'username': `${USERNAME}`
}
```

Also Is there any way to identify the proper error messages for the above APIs

Also I tried to call the API according to the [AWS Cognito Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ConfirmForgotPassword.html). But I am receiving bad request

```
const main = async () => {
    try {
        const AUTH_DOMAIN = "mydomain.regison.amazoncognito.com";
        const request_url = `https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/confirmforgotPassword`;
        const payload = {
            ClientId:"CLIENT_ID",
            ConfirmationCode:"****",
            Password:"***********",
            Username:"user email id",
            SecretHash:"XSRFTOKEN"
        }
        const response = await axios.post(request_url, payload);
        console.log(response)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

}

main()
```

Comment: Have you looked at this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ConfirmForgotPassword.html

Comment: @stijndepestel
 Yes. I look at them. See here for Forgot Password documentation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgotPassword.html

I sent client id and redirect uri as query param and username as request body. But it worked. Only Confirm Forgot password api's is not working as like above.